# Ambiguous chords in Bach's "Ich dank dir lieber Herre" setting (BWV 347)

Tags: chord-progressions, analysis, nonchord-tones

[image: mm. 11–12]

The image above shows, from Bach 371 Chorales, No. 2 "Ich dank dir lieber Herre" in A major, measures 11 and 12.

I'm very confused by this part.

***1. first red square, Is that chord I or vi56?***

**If that is I**, non chord tone 'F' is becomes a 7th note(G) in the next chord, and the 7th note goes up in the another next chord.

There is a theory that it is possible to ascend by steps when a resolution sound comes out of the bass of a chord with 7 notes, but I don't know if this applies to the Bach choral as well.

**if that is vi56**

7th note 'E' goes to 'D' but maybe D is a non chord tone in that chord, but I don't know if the 7th will go to a non-chord tone and can be resolved.

***2. second red square, that is I46 or maybe vi7 with out the root?***

this just can't figure it out anything..
first time i saw this i think maybe this chord is 'iii'
but if that iii, can't explain how non chord tone 'A' is resolved. because that's not a suspension or anticipation.

if that is I46, I don't know can come out like that.

and maybe vi7 with out root? i think that's not. but that's all i try..
so i appreciate to if you can help this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First red box**

The first chord is vi[6-5]. The chord on the half beat is viio[6-4], even those the B is missing, with the A service as a non-harmonic pedal tone. Thus, the progression is vi-vii-I.

**Second red box**

The chord here is a cadential 6-4 chord (I[6-4] or V[6-4] depending on who you're talking to), leading to the V chord on the following beat (not shown in the image).

**A note on analyzing Bach in particular and music in general**

It is tempting to try to label every single chord, but this is misleading. Bach was not composing this way — he was writing independent melodies, and later on, theorists came along and looked to give analytical explanations to his compositions.

Thus, many of Bach's "chords" are better seen as passing chords, expanding — but somewhat incidental to — a larger harmonic texture. In this light, it can be more productive to look at the first box as an expansion of the preceding V chord, with the A serving as an anticipation of the I chord.

Comment: thank you so much! pedal tone is make sense! (i thought pedal too but i was not sure about viio)

Comment: and you right. V came out next IV7 BUT but can use cadential 6-4 like that?

Comment: i mean can 'IV' came out next cadential I46? not the V?

Comment: You seem to have stumbled on the wrong BWV number.  BWV 254 is _Ach Gott, erhör mein Seufzen._

Comment: Aaron you there?

Comment: @guss2222 It's a bit unusual, but yes, IV can come after cadential I64. I would not consider it a IV7, however. The apparent 7 (C#), I would consider a suspension.

Comment: @Aaron that's not lV7? why not..? so what chord is that? And what do you think another answer from Derion Mukhalfa here? kind a different to your answer.

Comment: @guss2222 Although the notes look like IV7, the C# is a melodic, not a harmonic, element. Thus, it's a IV chord with a suspension. This is the difference between just naming chords versus analysis. The other answer, for example, focuses on naming chords, but does not provide a functional analysis of how the music operates. Bach did not write in terms of vertical structures; his priority was independent lines of music. Quartal harmony is an idea that came along much later, and has more to do with chord voicings in, say, jazz, than as a functional form of analysis.

Comment: @Aaron oh man ok. I think it just would be good to know like that.. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

First of all the notation I use: y=first invertion; x=second invertion; Q=quartal.

( Vy - V5 ) ( viy - IQ ) ( I - IM7sus2 ) ( vi7no5 - ii7x ) ( iii6y - IVM7 )

Quartal harmony is his own topic, vi to I and I to I are fairly simple, so nothing fancy in here. The last chord is C#m6 intead of A because C# is doubled, which makes us think about it as the tonic, but it still works as V/IV.

Comment: you sure? i'm not doubt you, just First time hearing this Quartal harmony. and if that is 'ii7x -> iii6y'.  how can explain 'A' is resolved? 7th in ii7x is moving to non chord tone and that non chord tone in iii6y is not a suspension or anticipation. it's messed up

Comment: man. i research that Quartal harmony (Quartal chord).  i think that was not use to bach age.

Comment: Quartal chords is when you build chords by stacking fourths instead of traditional triads. But that A it´s a pedal tone in that whole measure it doesn´t needs to be resolved, there´s not such such thing as a "messed up" when moving to a neighbour chord.

Comment: Quartal harmony is a really overlooked topic and there´s no real works about it. It is something we use to call things like C7sus4. Also in Mozart´s age augmented chords weren´t a thing and in one of his works he uses the four existent augmented triads.

Comment: Bach had a greater understanding of harmony than you and me together. Where we see chords he saw voices, independent melodies dancing together and that´s why he did what others couldn´t.

Comment: so you sure he use Quartal chords and 'A' in [ ii7x->iii6y->IV7 ] is pedal tone? but there is no tie and the note 'A' is not connected and are separated. I don't know pedal tone can come out that way.

Comment: Are you saying that the pedal tone 'A' starts at the first red box and continues with the voice part shifted up to IV7? and again, I don't know pedal tone can come out that way.

Comment: Look, the Alto part in the second measure remains on A, that's why is a pedal point. We don't know if Bach purpously did add a quartal chord, that's only my interpretation as AM7sus4 because if taken D as the root it makes no sense neither G#. Again, at the end of the day even if Quartal or not for me it's like a suspended I chord. It is ii7x because it spells F# D A B which is Bm7 starting on the fifth. C#m6 is the same as A, and A works as the dominant to IV. Keep your Focus on voice leading.

Comment: your analysis make sense too. i just wanted to know a pedal tone is can use like that way. and i think possible to different analysis. I will remember how to analyze like you. you teach me a lot, thank you so much.

Comment: Actually it is more common to see pedal tones in the tenor and bass voices, but in alto it's a bit strange. However if Bach does so do I.